# Image resize within browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, html

I want to reseize images with the browser. I tried:

```
<div id="imageWrapper">
  <img src="imageurl" />
</div>

<style> 
    #imageWrapper{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0 0 30px 30px}
    #imageWrapper img{width:100%;height:100%;}
</style>
```

This works fine for landscape pictures, but portrait-format images are scaling to the image-width and not to browser height. Instead I get an unwanted scrollbar and an image that needs scrolling. height:100% seems not to be working correctly in my case

I work in ASP.NET with C# in a ContentPlaceholder in my Masterpage. The imageUrl is filled in code-behind. So background images are not possible without dirty tricks.

What I hope to reach is that landscape pictures fill 100% viewport width and max viewport height, but portrait images fill 100% viewport height and max viewport width.

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like this:

```
<style>
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #imageWrapper{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     padding:0
  }
  #imageWrapper img{
     width:auto;
     height:100%;
  }
</style>

<div id="imageWrapper">
  <img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs12/i/2006/310/d/f/Value_Gray_Scale_Self_Portrait_by_stronglikemusic.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: add text-align:center; to keep your portrait images centered on the page

Answer (score 0):

For sizing, I would rather suggest using the `background-size` `cover` or `contain` properties like:

#### HTML

```
<div id="imageWrapper">
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url(imageurl);" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
    #imageWrapper{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0 0 30px 30px
     }
    #imageWrapper .image{
         width:100%; 
         height:100%;
         background-size: cover; /* or contain */
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center;
    }
```

#### Otherwise,

your problem is with the `padding`, because that adds to the `width: 100%;`

In other words: if the parent was `100x100px` then the total size of `#imageWrapper` becomes `130x130px` because of the extra `30px` padding on the `bottom` and `right`. Thus the scrollbars.

Here a solution would be an `overflow: hidden;` on the element that has the scrollbars (and then it should be sized accordingly).

Comment: I work with ASP:NET en I use C# to fill the imageUrl in code-behind, so background images are not possible.